# mse loss function not compatible with regularization loss (add_loss) on hidden layer output

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, layer, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

I would like to code in tf.Keras a Neural Network with a couple of loss functions. One is a standard mse (mean squared error) with a factor loading, while the other is basically a regularization term on the output of a hidden layer. This second loss is added through `self.add_loss()` in a user-defined class inheriting from `tf.keras.layers.Layer`. I have a couple of questions (the first is more important though).

**1)** The error I get when trying to combine the two losses together is the following:

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1
        From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for '{{node AddN}} = AddN[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT](loss/weighted_loss/value, model/new_layer/mul_1)' with input shapes: [], [100].
```

So it comes from the fact that the tensors which should add up to make one unique loss value have different shapes (and ranks). Still, when I try to print the losses during the training, I clearly see that the vectors returned as losses have shape `batch_size` and rank 1. Could it be that when the 2 losses are summed I have to provide them (or at least the loss of `add_loss`) as scalar? I know the mse is usually returned as a vector where each entry is the mse from one sample in the batch, hence having `batch_size` as shape. I think I tried to do the same with the "regularization" loss. Do you have an explanation for this behavio(u)r?

The sample code which gives me error is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input


def rate_mse(rate=1e5):
    @tf.function # also needed for printing
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        tmp = rate*K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
#        tf.print('shape %s and rank %s output in mse'%(K.shape(tmp), tf.rank(tmp)))
        tf.print('shape and rank output in mse',[K.shape(tmp), tf.rank(tmp)])
        tf.print('mse loss:',tmp) # print when I put tf.function
        return tmp
    return loss

class newLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, rate=5e-2, **kwargs):
        super(newLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.rate = rate
        
#    @tf.function # to be commented for NN training
    def call(self, inputs):
        tmp = self.rate*K.mean(inputs*inputs, axis=-1)
        tf.print('shape and rank output in regularizer',[K.shape(tmp), tf.rank(tmp)])
        tf.print('regularizer loss:',tmp)
        self.add_loss(tmp, inputs=True)
        return inputs



tot_n = 10000
xx = np.random.rand(tot_n,1)
yy = np.pi*xx

train_size = int(0.9*tot_n)
xx_train = xx[:train_size]; xx_val = xx[train_size:]
yy_train = yy[:train_size]; yy_val = yy[train_size:]

reg_layer = newLayer()

input_layer = Input(shape=(1,))                                      # input
hidden = Dense(20, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,))(input_layer) # hidden layer
hidden = reg_layer(hidden)
output_layer = Dense(1, activation='linear')(hidden) 

model = Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[output_layer])
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=rate_mse(), experimental_run_tf_function=False)
#model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=None, experimental_run_tf_function=False)
model.fit(xx_train, yy_train, epochs=100, batch_size = 100, 
          validation_data=(xx_val,yy_val), verbose=1)

#new_xx = np.random.rand(10,1); new_yy = np.pi*new_xx
#model.evaluate(new_xx,new_yy)


print(model.predict(np.array([[1]])))
```

**2)** I would also have a secondary question related to this code. I noticed that printing with `tf.print` inside the function `rate_mse` only works with `tf.function`. Similarly, the `call` method of `newLayer` is only taken into consideration if the same decorator is commented during training. Can someone explain why this is the case or reference me to a possible solution?

Thanks in advance to whoever can provide me help. I am currently using Tensorflow 2.2.0 and keras version is 2.3.0-tf.

Comment: Have you found the answer on your own yet? I'm still unable to figure out what to do to make this work.

Comment: @MikeMartin no, sorry. In the end, I had to ignore this.

Answer (score 2):

I stuck with the same problem for a few days. "Standard" loss is going to be a scalar at the moment when we add it to the loss from add_loss. The only way how I get it working is to add one more axis while calculating mean. So we will get a scalar, and it will work.

```
tmp = self.rate*K.mean(inputs*inputs, axis=[0, -1])
```